# LibreOffice - Can I link text?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, links

I would like to link text in LibreOffice in a way that, if I change one, it adjusts the other. Specifically, I have a title and want to use that as header on the following pages. When I change the title the header should automatically adjust. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - for such a task, you may use a **[field](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Fields)**. Fields are a very powerful concept, fitting different use cases. In your case, you could put a [**chapter field**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Document) in the **[header](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/About_Headers_and_Footers)** that automatically takes the current chapter heading (you'll have to define the heading level).

### References to headings

To insert such a field:

1. Insert a header (Menu "Insert" -> "Header and Footer" -> "Header" -> "Default style";
2. put the cursor into the header;
3. Menu "Insert" -> "Field" -> "More fields", or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
4. Select the "document" tab; there, in the "Type" list, select Chapter; in the "Format" list, select "Chapter name" (or any other entry); in the lower right corner, select the heading level to use.
5. Click <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Now, every page should have a header with the current Level xy heading inside. If you modify the heading, the header entry should automatically change, too.

If you want that header to appear only on certain pages, you need to use different page styles and switch between them; see the docs on "*[Defining Different Headers and Footers](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Different_Headers_and_Footers)*"

### References to any piece of text

For a "generic" cross-reference, working with any piece of text:

1. Select the "anchor text" to be referenced:

   [image]
2. Menu "Insert" -> "Field" -> "More fields", or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Select the "Cross-reference" tab;

   - in the Input field above the the "Value" field, insert a unique name;
   - double-click on the "Set Reference" entry in the "Type" list; now, the unique name should appear in the Selection List:

     [image]
   - click <kbd>Close</kbd>
4. Move the cursor to where the reference should appear;
5. Menu "Insert" -> "Field" -> "More fields", or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
6. On the cross-reference tab, from the "Type" Listbox, select "Insert Reference"; in the Selection List, select the name set in step 3a; in the "Insert reference to" listbox, select "Reference" (double-click OR single click + Insert Button):

   [image]
7. Now, when modifying the text selected in step 1, the text inserted in step 6 should dynamically change, too:

   [image]

   [image]

To make LO update the fields automatically, check the settings:

[image]

Comment: Ah, cross-references! Wow I love this and gonna put this to use as often as I can now :)

Comment: Hm okay I thought that it worked now, but apparently it does NOT ADAPT to the changes I make. I did it the exact same way you've explained :/

Comment: I just updated to the newest version, the tick is there, but it still doesn't update automatically... Seems like a bug to me?

Comment: Here: https://ufile.io/c6i5n. Interestingly, when i export it as pdf, it does a refresh and displays correctly

Comment: Ok - now i can reproduce it - the position of the inserted reference seems to matter - inserting it into the same paragraph but not immediately before the paragraph mark works (my example); inserting the reference as sole content of a new paragraph doesn't (your example). Modifying the paragraph containing the reference triggers a refresh, too. In fact, looks like a bug... :-(

Comment: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112882 ...